# Alternate for GooglePlayServices in BB10 Android RunTime

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I ported an android app to BB 10. Using android runtime,after repackaging to .BAR, app runs fine except GooglePlayServices: com.google.android.gms.Application crashes when I go to screens related to this. I checked the classes that I am using from this library are:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

and some implementations are GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener.
For google maps I have found the alternate solution for BB 10 in android runtime documentation. 
What is the alternate solution for this library classes??

Comment: It would useful if we knew why you need those services for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStreetMap [is available as a replacement](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/replacing_google_maps.html) for Google Maps in GooglePlayServices. I was under the impression that this was automatic, but I'm not currently working on Android so I don't have any direct experience.

Comment: its not just Google maps. What about other classes in GooglePlayServices?

Comment: As far as I know, they are not available. The BlackBerry Android runtime is more like the Android runtime in an Amazon Kindle Fire than an Open Handset Alliance device.